# Event based programming inside a Spring web app controller on Tomcat or Jetty

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

HTTP controller (Spring) gets a requests and making a blocking call. Once the blocking call is over the controls get back to the controller.

At this point I don't want to send a response back to the client but rather wait for another event(e.g., completion of some processing) to happen. As soon as that event happens I need a way to collect the data from the event and then return the HTTP response with this data.

```
HTTPController doSomething( HTTPRequest ) 
{
    makeBlockingCall();  
    waitForEventToHappen();
    collectDataFromEvent();

    return HTTPResponse(); 

}
```

Comment: Stripped tomcat from the tags. There is nothing tomcat-specific about this question. A solution will behave in tomcat just like in any other web container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't do that from within one request, because that would probably time out eventually and until then wouldn't provide feedback to the customer that something is happening.

Instead, you would immediately show a page that asynchronously (probably per AJAX) polls the server to see whether the result is already available.

So the first request will return an id that will be used in the second (AJAX) request to lookup the result.

Comment: The event happens quite fast (in a few seconds), so timeout is not going to be an issue.

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta but a few seconds is a long time for synchronous processing.